# How to use BlurDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

someone can tell me how to import and use this library in Android studio?
It doesn't work if I only add the dependencies in build.gradle
https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried add as following three steps:

1. on `top` build.gradle

[image]

2. on `app` build.gradle

[image]

3. If do not see the class at first, may go `File--> invalidate Caches/Restart`

Then you will see the class:

[image]

Comment: Now I imported the library, but how should I use the blurDialogEngine to avoid inheritance?

Comment: You can get code form [here](https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment#avoiding-inheritance)